# meteor helpers only return first batch

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have a simple meteor app that displays batches and when I click on the batch, it will list the individual documents. There are individual `log` button assigned to these batches listing that is supposed to pull a modal which displays the technical log listing of documents belonging to corresponding batches. However, the helper function loads all the log helper while navigating to batch listing page on page load and not on click, and all log buttons brings information of first batch only.

Here are my helpers:

```
Template.log.helpers
    batchTransactions: (_id) ->
        transactions = C.Transactions.find {batchId:_id}, sort: createdAt: -1
        transactions
```

My log template:

```
<template name="log">
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#log" class="pointer font-small">
    View Log
  </a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="log" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Log">
    <div id="batch-summary" class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Batch Summary</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            {{#each batchTransactions _id}}
                <li> {{log}} </li>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

This log template is nested inside batchlisting template:

```
  <template name="home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    {{#each batchList}}
                         {{> log}}
                    {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
   </template>
```

Helper for batchlist:

```
Template.home.helpers
    batchList: ->
        batches = C.Batches.find {}, sort: createdAt: -1
        batches
```

Can you help me out here?

Comment: Your modals are built when your log template is rendered because you are only showing/hiding divs on button click, not actually creating them at that point. Your script to find the transactions looks correct. Is your publication on the server serving up all the transactions related to a batch?

Comment: yep everything else is fine, published. the only problem is modal association. can you elaborate on the showing/hiding and not actually creating part please? I think that is the problem.

Comment: You can use bootbox.js for example to create a modal in code. Or you could leave the modal section empty and then use `Blaze.renderWithData()` to fill it in on click using a template. Basically you want to keep that nested `{{#each batchTransactions _id}}` out of the template until the button has been clicked.

Comment: @MichelFloyd So far my understanding is when I pass the `_id` of individual batches to `batchTransaction` in `log` template helper, it should return the transaction belonging to that batchId as the mongo query suggests...

Comment: @MichelFloyd okie... thanks, I will try that...